# 403 Forbidden Rails/Capistrano/Puma EC2 Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, capistrano, puma

There are a ton of these questions, I've read a lot of them, still unable to figure out what's going wrong for me.

The error log in my console

```
2016/08/02 09:43:27 [error] 5484#0: *2 directory index of 
"/home/deploy/appname/current/" is forbidden, client: 173.245.52.241, 
server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "appname.com"
```

Here's my nginx conf

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/appname/shared/tmp/sockets/appname-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name appname.com;

  root /home/deploy/appname/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/appname/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/appname/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on; 
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10; 
}
```

Thought it might have been a permissions issue so I ran `chmod -R 755` on my project folder to no avail.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Directory permissions run to the upper level. If the Nginx user can't read `/home/` it doesn't matter what permissions you set on `'/home/deploy/appname/`. As a debug, set your Nginx user (in your `nginx.conf`) to your current user (the one that owns `home`), restart the server, and check if the error persists.

Comment: tried setting the user to deploy, still not working.

Comment: Do you see any information in the access or error logs you've specified above?

Comment: Unfortunately not anything different in the error logs, I see the same output that "/home/deploy/appname/current/" is forbidden